# Transfer all related models to different user in Django

Tags: django

In my django 1.8 app I can get all linked objects from other models of a user with `user._meta.get_fields()`. I now want to update/transfer all linked objects to point to an admin user.

This is what I've tried:

```
In [6]: from danube.people.models import Profile

In [7]: admin = Profile.objects.get(id=1000)

In [8]: user = Profile.objects.get(id=1002)

In [9]: userData = user._meta.get_fields()

In [10]: for item in userData:
    ...:     extModel = item(related_model=admin)
    ...:     # extModel = item(related_model_id=1000)
    ...:     extModel.save()
    ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-aa9ee22a4e75> in <module>()
      1 for item in userData:
----> 2     extModel = item(related_model=admin)
      3     extModel.save()
      4 

TypeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object is not callable
```

How can I overcome the `TypeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object is not callable` Error?

Comment: what about `user.user.is_staff = True` or `user.user.is_superuser = True` and then `user.user.save()`? Maybe an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: good point. But I'd like to delete the user afterward but do not want to loose linked objects. Just saw there is 'SET ' for on_delete. Added to the user model this might help?! My overall plan was to give admins some dropdown in django admin to define who should inherit the objects :/  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#arguments

Comment: Okay, I'm going to write an answer and it might work for you, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

The following are shell commands in your Django environment. It is a possible alternative solution to what you have attempted so far.

```
old_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1002)
old_profile.pk = None
old_profile.save()

# Old profile is now a new object
old_profile.user.is_staff = True
old_profile.user.is_superuser = True
old_profile.user.save()

Profile.objects.get(id=1002).delete()  # Delete the old user profile
```

This will make a copy of the old user and then set it to have admin rights. It will delete the old instance as well. Maybe this fits your needs! Good luck.

EDIT: You can try something like this (haven't tested it, so beware)

Another idea is to change the `User` associated with each profile. So you have your admin `User` and your profile that you want to keep the associated objects of.

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1002)
old_user = profile.user
admin_user = Profile.objects.get(id=1000).user
profile.user = admin_user
profile.save()
Profile.objects.get(id=1000).delete()
```

Now your admin `User` will be linked to the profile with `id=1002`. Maybe that will help?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sam Creamer , this is definitly helpful. One question. My aim would be to not create a new admin user but to transfer all linked objects to always the same user with pid 1000. Do you see a chance to get this done?

Comment: Sorry to say @Sam Creamer , but I think there is still a misunderstanding. Let me explain again. Imagine you have a user Toni (id 1002) which has different relations to objects. And an admin Sam (id 1000). Now when you delete Toni in Django backend it will warn you that all related objects get deleted. I would look for a way to transfer all related objects from Toni to Sam. That I do not lose data and can safely delete Toni. I know of on_delete on fk definition but would look for a way to have it as management command like ([pseudo code] manage.py transfer_objects --from=Toni --to Sam)

Comment: I will sneak around in Django Code to see how they actually do the magic with on_delete in case you have an idea or starting point I will owe you not only one beer :))

Comment: You can change the on_delete attribute to a variety of things that will not delete the objects. You can write a script (as you did) to change the relation of the objects from one profile to another quite easily! You were on the right track originally. I just offered two separate approaches to duplicating or transferring relationships.